# Is it possible to declare multiple variables with a for loop in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, for-loop, actionscript

I'm trying to create a platformer with randomly generated platforms but so far I've had to declare each platform one by one. This is a problem for me because if I want to make say, one hundred floors to my level, I need to declare 100 Sprites, then the collision for each sprite. Is there any easier way to do this other than the way I've been doing it up until now?

This is what I've got:

```
    public var piso1:Sprite;
    public var piso2:Sprite;
    public var piso3:Sprite;
    public var piso4:Sprite;
    public var piso5:Sprite;
    public var piso6:Sprite;
    public var piso7:Sprite;
    public var piso8:Sprite;
    public var piso9:Sprite;
    public var piso10:Sprite;
    public var piso11:Sprite;
    public var piso12:Sprite;
    public var piso13:Sprite;
    public var piso14:Sprite;
    public var piso15:Sprite;
    public var piso16:Sprite;
    public var piso17:Sprite;
    public var piso18:Sprite;
    public var piso19:Sprite;
    public var piso20:Sprite;
    public var pisoganar:Sprite;
```

Since these are sprites, this is how I make them:

```
    public function cuadrados():void
    {
        for (var i:int =0; i<20; i++)
        {
            pisos[i] = dibujarCuadrado(0x000000, 100 + (Math.random() * (200 - 50 + 1) + 1), 25);       
        }

        piso2 = pisos[0]
        piso3 = pisos[1]
        piso4 = pisos[2]
        piso5 = pisos[3]
        piso6 = pisos[4]
        piso7 = pisos[5]
        piso8 = pisos[6]
        piso9 = pisos[7]
        piso10 = pisos[8]
        piso11 = pisos[9]
        piso12 = pisos[10]
        piso13 = pisos[11]
        piso14 = pisos[12]
        piso15 = pisos[13]
        piso16 = pisos[14]
        piso17 = pisos[15]
        piso18 = pisos[16]
        piso19 = pisos[17]
        piso20 = pisos[18]
    }
```

And then I set each one's position, one by one:

```
        piso1.x = stage.stageWidth /2;
        piso1.y = 600;

        piso2.x = stage.stageWidth /2;
        piso2.y = 500;

        piso3.x = piso2.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso3.y = 400;

        piso4.x = piso3.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso4.y = 300;

        piso5.x = piso4.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso5.y = 200;

        piso6.x = piso5.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso6.y = 100;

        piso7.x = piso6.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso7.y = 0;

        piso8.x = piso7.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso8.y = -100;

        piso9.x = piso8.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso9.y = -200;

        piso10.x = piso9.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso10.y = -300;

        piso11.x = piso10.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso11.y = -400;

        piso12.x = piso11.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso12.y = -500;

        piso13.x = piso12.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso13.y = -600;

        piso14.x = piso13.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso14.y = -700;

        piso15.x = piso14.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso15.y = -800;

        piso16.x = piso15.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso16.y = -900;

        piso17.x = piso16.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso17.y = -1000;

        piso18.x = piso17.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso18.y = -1100;

        piso19.x = piso18.x - (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso19.y = -1200;

        piso20.x = piso19.x + (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
        piso20.y = -1300;

        pisoganar = dibujarCuadrado(0x00FF00,800, 25);
        pisoganar.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        pisoganar.y = -1400;
```

So, yeah. A lot of code. Is there any way to simplify this? (I'm natively spanish, so the variables are all in spanish. "Piso" means floor, "cuadrados" is square and "dibujarcuadrado" is my draw square function, basically it creates, fills and places the square in the stage) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have so much redundant code. Assuming `dibujarCuadrado` returns a `Sprite`, you can do this instead of ALL that code posted:

```
var tmpSprite:Sprite; //only need to define one

var tmpX:Number = stage.stageWidth /2; //store the current x
var tmpY:Number = 600; //store the starting y

var tmpRand:Number; //temporary variable to hold the random value every iteration

var pisos:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>(); //this array holds all your sprites

for (var i:int =0; i<20; i++)
{

    tmpSprite = dibujarCuadrado(0x000000, 100 + (Math.random() * (200 - 50 + 1) + 1), 25);  
    pisos.push(tmpSprite); //add to the array

    tmpRand = (Math.random() * (400 - 100 + 1) + 100);
    if(i % 2 == 0){ //the i % 2 is the remainder of i divided by 2, this make the condition alternate every iteration
        tmpSprite.x = tmpX - tmpRand;
    }else{
        tmpSprite.x = tmpX + tmpRand;
    }

    tmpX = tmpSprite.x;

    tmpSprite.y = tmpY - (100 * i);
}
```

This code could be even further reduced (less variables, inline conditionals) but I wanted to keep as easy to understand as possible.